# How to Handle too many tabs (sections) in MS OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I've been using OneNote for more than a year. My problem is that number of sections (tabs) are growing and I have more than 70 sections in one of my notebooks which makes it hard to navigate and find relevant materials. I don't want to delete them because they are still relevant and useful.

How should I handle them? Is there a way to archive them based on their date, similar to a blog?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use "Section Group". They help to organize your sections. To create one, simply right-click on a section name or anywhere on that bar above the page, and select New Section Group.

Answer (score 5):

There is not a built in method of archiving within OneNote.

There are, however, ways to make your own manual archive.

The simplest would be to create a new notebook and manually move items into it that you no longer need.

A better option may be to more aggressively organize your notebook so you have fewer sections (tabs across the top) and more pages. OneNote itself should be able to handle a large notebook just fine, and if you're looking for a way to decrease the number of tabs, this is probably how to do it best and most easily.

Comment: Agreed, you can also make notes at 3 different "levels" within a tab which helps organise many notes, you can collapse the first level to get a more manageable index.

Answer (score 2):

Though you cannot automatically archive, you might consider making your whole notebook an archive and starting a new notebook or even several. Drag over any notes you need right now.

I use around a dozen notebooks, each for a different subject. Some date back years to the early days of OneNote and are rarely used but always only a search away.

Search is the best thing (well actually one of many "best things" ;) in OneNote. Since you can even search hand written notes and audio/video files.